# Migrating from log4j 1.x into log4j 2.x

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm using log4j 1.2.16 in my application.

now due to Java Log4j vulnerabilities(remote code execution) I'm upgrading to 2.17.2(log4j 2.x)

here is the reference manual in the apache website.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

so here my question is, even if migrate from 1.x to 2.x using bridge-api still I'm potential to vulnerable for remote code execution.?

If yes is there any performance impact?

Comment: Identify the tool that detected the vulnerability and include the full text of the vulnerability.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just exclude original log4j 1.x and use [reload4j](https://reload4j.qos.ch/) instead.